# Remove attribute "disabled" from submit button in Twitter Bootstrap after fields are validated

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In a form I want to remove the attribute disabled="disabled" after the validation on the form is passed.

The validation itself works, but my submit button doesn't work. It must be active only when all fields are green.

the code in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7FYPY/

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the lengthy code, but this seems to be working
(removed `return`s and check for `empty`, and replaced `blur` with `bind('blur keyup')`)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var name_error = 1;
    var email_error = 1;
    var message_error = 1;

    // Check name field
    $('#name').bind('blur keyup', function() {
        $('#name_msg').html("");
        var name = $('#name').val();

        if (name === '') {
            name_error = 1;
            $('#name-group').addClass('error');
            $('#name_msg').append('Field is empty');
        } else if (name.length < 2) {
            name_error = 1;
            $('#name-group').addClass('error');
            $('#name_msg').append('Must be at leas 2 characters long');
        } else {
            name_error = 0;
            $('#name-group').removeClass('error');
            $('#name-group').addClass('success');
        }
        enableButton();
    });

    // check email field
    $('#email').bind('blur keyup', function() {
        $('#email_msg').html("");
        var email = $('#email').val();

        var reEmail = /^[A-Za-z0-9._-][a-zA-Z0-9._-][A-Za-z0-9._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{2,4}$/;

        if (email === '') {
            email_error = 1;
            $('#email-group').addClass('error');
            $('#email_msg').append('Field is empty');
        } else if (!reEmail.test(email)) {
            email_error = 1;
            $('#email-group').addClass('error');
            $('#email_msg').append('Email is not valid');
        } else {
            email_error = 0;
            $('#email-group').removeClass('error');
            $('#email-group').addClass('success');
         }
        enableButton();
    });

    // check message field
    $('#message').bind('blur keyup', function() {
        $('#message_msg').html("");
        var message = $('#message').val();

        if (message === '') {
            message_error = 1;
            $('#message-group').addClass('error');
            $('#message_msg').append('Field is empty');
        } else if (message.length < 6) {
            message_error = 1;
            $('#message-group').addClass('error');
            $('#message_msg').append('Must be at leas 6 characters long');
        } else {
            message_error = 0;
            $('#message-group').removeClass('error');
            $('#message-group').addClass('success');
        }
        enableButton();
    });

    // verzendknop pas activeren nadat alles is ingevuld en gecontroleerd
    function enableButton() {
        if (name_error!== 0 || email_error!== 0 || message_error !== 0) {
            $('#sendit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#sendit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This works as expected. When all fields are green and the user adjusts one of them so it turns red again, the submit button is disabled again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the problem is the selector you have for the keyup binding:  $('form > input')
That selector will apply to all input fields directly below the form tag. For more info about child selectors, read http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

It should work if you change it to this:

```
// verzendknop pas activeren nadat alles is ingevuld en gecontroleerd
    $('form  input').keyup(function() {
        var empty = 0;
        $('form  input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === '') {
                empty = 1;
                return empty;
            }
        });

        if (empty || name_error || email_error || message_error !== 0) {
            $('#sendit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#sendit').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
```

Comment: The code doesn't work (http://jsfiddle.net/w4rzX/), but I do appreciate the answer and the link to child selector.

Comment: Ok, what is it that doesn't work in the fiddle you refer to? What I can se the #sendit button is enabled in that fiddle when the name and email is filled in correctly. If you want the message field to be in the loop then use this selector instead: $('form :input')